# How to create a reusable checkbox component using Angular 8?

Tags: angular-forms, angular8

I'm trying to create a reusable checkbox component with Angular 8, using the CheckboxControlValueAccessor. I can't understand what should I write in the "writeValue" and "onChange" functions, so that the value of the checkbox will get "checked" on each click.

Already manage to create reusable input component with ControlValueAccessor and Validator.